# Restrictions in terms of using external libraries (Python) in a Storm Bolt

Tags: python, scikit-learn, apache-storm

I want to implement a Bolt (https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm)  that does some heavy processing on a tuples using scikit Machine Learning API (http://scikit-learn.org/)

For example -

```
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import datasets

trans_corpus = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
tfidf = text.TfidfTransformer().fit_transform(trans_corpus)
...
...
```

Is this possible ? 
Is having sklearn and all it's dependencies installed on each node in the cluster enough?

Comment: I install all my python dependencies using `pip` when launching a new supervisor.

Comment: Installing scipy with pip can be complex because of the blas, lapack and gfortran dependencies which cannot be installed with pip themselves. Also building numpy and scipy can take a long time. Better use the package manager of the distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, it should be possible unless there is something really weird about scikit I don't know. You just need to build your topologies such that you can write your bolts in Python, which I suspect you already know is possible and there are plenty of examples.